# extracting certain strings from a a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file with some lines. Out of those lines I will choose only lines which starts with `xxx`.  Now the lines which starts with `xxx` have pattern as follows:

```
xxx:(12:"pqrs",223,"rst",-90)
xxx:(23:"abc",111,"def",-80)
```

I want to extract only the string which are their in the first double quote
i.e., "pqrs" and "abc".

Any help using regex is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
with open("log.txt","r") as f:
         f = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        line=line.rstrip()
        for phrase in 'xxx:':
             if re.match('^xxx:',line):
                 c=line
                 break
```

this code is giving me error

Comment: can you provide given input and  required output ?

Comment: Why don't you use easily understandable split functionality instead? How do you want to maintain a regex you were unable to create?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrongly indented. Your `f = f.readlines()` has 9 spaces in front while `for line in f:` has 4 spaces. It should look like below.

```
import re
list_of_prefixes = ["xxx","aaa"]
resulting_list = []
with open("raw.txt","r") as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        for line in f:
            line=line.rstrip()
            for phrase in list_of_prefixes:
                if re.match(phrase + ':\(\d+:\"(\w+)',line) != None:
                    resulting_list.append(re.findall(phrase +':\(\d+:\"(\w+)',line)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
with open("log.txt","r") as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("xxx"):
            line = line.split(":")  # line[1] will be what is after :
            result = line[1].split(",")[0][1:-1] # will be pqrs
            results.append(result)
```

You want to look for lines that start with xxx
then split the line on the :.  The first thing after the : is what you want -- up to the comma.  Then your result is that string, but remove the quotes.  There is no need for regex.  Python string functions will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Well you are heading in the right direction.

If the input is this simple, you can use regex groups.

```
with open("log.txt","r") as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        line=line.rstrip()
        m = re.match('^xxx:\(\d*:("[^"]*")',line)
        if m is not None:
            print(m.group(1))
```

All the magic is in the regular expression.

^xxx:(\d*:("[^"]*") means

Start from the beginning of the line, match on "xxx:(<any number of numbers>:"<anything but ">"

and because the sequence "<anything but ">" is enclosed in round brackets it will be available as a group (by calling m.group(1)).

PS: next time make sure to include the exact error you are getting

Comment: Thank u so much. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a line starts with *xxx* do

```
line.startswith('xxx')
```

To find the text in first double-quotes do

```
re.search(r'"(.*?)"', line).group(1)
```

(as `match.group(1)` is the first parenthesized subgroup)

So the code will be

```
with open("file") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('xxx'):
            print(re.search(r'"(.*?)"', line).group(1))
```

[re module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)

Comment: Thank u so much. I am new in regex.Can u please suggest me some link or something from where i can have clear understanding about regex. thanx again.

Comment: @RamakantaChandra Try the documentation.